# Filter values to php array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is a variable read that outputs the below results

```
 $read = s1 0kg s2 2939kg s3 193kg s4 10kg;
```

how do i filter the values such that i only obtain the values before 'kg' and have them in an array
the output should be

```
$read = {0,2939,193,10}
```

Comment: Please don't ask same (basically) two questions on this site. It won't help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of regular expressions, it is:

```
$read = 's1 0kg s2 2939kg s3 193kg s4 10kg';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/(\d+)kg/', $read, $matches);
// with `minus` sign
// preg_match_all('/(\-?\d+)kg/', $read, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/YEHKr).

Comment: have notices that the $read variable keeps changing meaining that it may change to 
$read = 's1 0kg s3 -90kg s4 193kg s2 49Kg'; how do i make it to follow the s1 to s4 to display an array with [0,49,-90,193]